# What is NativeArray in javascript? How different it is from normal arrays?

Tags: javascript

Just happen to come across a type called "NativeArray" in JavaScript. Not sure what is that type and how different it is from normal arrays? When to use this type?

Please help

-Nayan

Comment: There's no such class in JavaSE.

Comment: *Where* did you come across that class?

Comment: My bad.. it is not in Java but is in JavaScript... Sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an exposed javascript type but a class used in [Mozilla's rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) to implement the javascript native (thus normal) array. It's possible you'd find similarly named types in other javascript engine implementations.

So :

- it's not really different from the native array (depending on the signification of "different")
- you shouldn't have this preoccupation when coding in javascript

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a special thing/array in `javascript` known as `native array` rather than the native javascript (normal) array.

> The only different in `javascript` array is that `javascript` doesn't
>   `have associative array` like many other languages have.

So in `javascript` you can assign arrays in so many ways:

```
var myCars=new Array(); // a blank array
myCars[0]="Ferrari";
myCars[1]="BMW";
```

or

```
var myCars=new Array('Ferrari', 'BMW'); // alert(myCars[0]); // Ferrari
```

or

```
var myCars=[]; // a blank array
myCars[0]="Ferrari";
myCars[1]="BMW";
```

or

```
var myCars=['Ferrari', 'BMW']; // alert(myCars[0]); // Ferrari
```